# Saying Selichos on fast days?

Tags: selichot

Say the is a man who chooses to fast on Bahab, where Selichos are said in between Shemoneh Esrei and Tachanun. Let's say he finishes Shemoneh Esrei and sees that he only has 15 minutes before he goes to work. Would it be preferable for him to say Selichos or to say Ashrei through HaYom Yom. If it'd be better for him to skip Selichos, can he say them later in the day?

Comment: Is he at a Minyan?

Comment: @double AA, yes.